# reduce database query to one and avoid Call to a member function load() on null error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this function:

```
public function show($id)

    {

        if (count($post = Post::find($id))) {

            $post = $post->load(['comments' => function ($q) {
                $q->latest();
                $q->with(['author' => function ($q) {

                    $q->select('id', 'username');

                }]);
            }, 'user' => function ($q) {

                $q->select('id', 'username');

            }]);

            $this->authorize('seePost', $post);

            return view('post.show', ['post' => $post]);

        } else {

            dd('no post');
        }

    }
```

I added the if statement as if I try to open a route to a non existent post id I get the error `Call to a member function load() on null`.
However now I have two queries, one looks for the `Post` in the DB and if it finds one then I have to load the relations with the second one. What can I do to go back to just one query with all the relations loaded and avoid the error? Any clue?

Comment: You shouldn't have to wrap `$post = Post::find($id)` with `count()`; it's gonna return a `Post` or `null`, so the `if(...)` on it's own should be fine. Depending on your PHP version, this might actually throw a different error: `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`, of which `null` does not. (I forget what version that came into being, but 7ish, I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Constraining Eager Loads do it like this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

```
$post = Post::with(["comments" => function ($query) {
        // Order by created_at, query comment author & select id, username
        $query->latest()->with(["author" => function ($q) {
            $q->select("id", "username");
        }]);

    }, "user" => function ($query) {
        // Query post author & select id,username
        $query->select("id", "username");
    }])

    // Fetch post or throw a 404 if post is missing
    ->findOrFail($id);

    // You can also return an empty post instance like this if post is missing
    // ->findOrNew([]);

    // Or return the post or null if post is missing
    // ->find($id);

    // Authorize
    $this->authorize('seePost', $post);

    return view("post.show", ["post" => $post]);
```

Comment: cool, thanks, this throws a 404 if I follow a route to a missing id.

Comment: If you do not want  a 404 thrown,  you can use find() instead of findOrFail() as indicated on the comments. Method find() will return null if no post is found matching the id.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has an Eager Loading feature that would be helpfull in your case. Eager Loading allows you to autoload relations along with the same query that you use to retrieve your main model info. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

You could a below codes.

Easiest way is :

```
$post = Post::with('comments.author', 'user')
                ->find($id);
```

Or fine tune query with callback :

```
$post = Post::with(['comments' => function ($q) {
            // if you use comments select, then you need to specify foreign key too
            $q->select('id', 'author_id', 'details') // comment fields
                ->latest(); // Use chaining method
            // OR use $q = $q->latest();
        },
        'comments.author' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'username'); // author fields
        },
        'user' => function ($) {
            $q->select('id', 'username'); // user fields
        }])
        ->find($id);
```

In some cases you might need some modifications, bu in overall that should avoid you `N+1` queries problem.

Comment: I’ll try that on Monday. Thanks